# actions on order ids question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I''d like to have the controller which can process soemthing like

http://***/query/id

which id represents an order id and has a lot of valid value.

can I achieve this using MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Set your routes and you are good to go:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Query",
    "query/{id}",
    new { controller = "Query", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and in your QueryController:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    ... do something with the id here    
}
```